# html form values reset after touch, on mobile browsers

Tags: javascript, jquery, mobile

I have a form, after `document.ready()` I load data into this form, but form values (device name) was cleared on mobile browsers, after tap on screen.

```js
$.ajax({
  type: 'GET',
  url: "api.ashx",
  data: "operation=device.get&deviceid=" + deviceid,
  success: function(response) {
    var apiResponse = jQuery.parseJSON(response);
    if (apiResponse.result == 'true') {
      $("#name").val(apiResponse.name);
      if (apiResponse.online == 'true') {
        $("#status").html('<span class="label label-success">online</span>');
      } else {
        $("#status").html('<span class="label label-red">offline</span> Был в сети: ' + apiResponse.lastvisit);
      }
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="deviceinfoform" action="#" class="form-horizontal">
  <div class="form-body">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">Device name <span class="require">*</span>
      </label>
      <div class="col-sm-6 controls">
        <input id="name" name="name" required="" type="text" placeholder="Device name" maxlength="100" class="form-control"></input>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">Device status</label>
      <div class="col-sm-6 controls">
        <div id="status" class="form-control">
          <span class="label label-success">online</span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is solved. The problem was in bootstrap-responsive-tabs plug-in.

```
fakewaffle.toggleResponsiveTabContent = function () {

var tabGroups = $('.nav-tabs.responsive');

$.each(tabGroups, function () {
    var tabs = $(this).find('li a');

    $.each(tabs, function () {
        var href         = $(this).attr('href').replace(/#/g, ''),
            tabId        = "#" + href,
            panelId      = "#collapse-" + href,
            tabContent   = $(tabId).html(),
            panelContent = $(panelId + " div:first-child").html();

        //!!!clear all dynamic content
        $(tabId).html(panelContent);
        $(panelId + " div:first-child").html(tabContent); 
    });

});
```

};

**Updating to the latest version solved a problem.**